# Add modal window in node content for each element I add

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, orgchart

I'm working right now with the Library jquery.orgchart.js.

I have different level in my orgchart that I show and everything is fine.
For the last level, people want to see each people in the team, in the same node, and with a link that popup to show an image with some text.

For the node, we can add a secondmenu like in this example : https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart/issues/37

I would like to know if it is possible to have a popup for each element(each employee) I add in the node on hover or onclick.
Here is the code of my button dialogmodal from bootstrap :

OnHover : It shows only the title and not the data-content :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Test en cours" data-content="You gotta go through it to see there aint nothing to it. Listen to the silence."> Hover 1</button>

                $(document).ready(function() {
                       $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                          placement: 'bottom',
                          trigger: 'click',
                          title: 'Sign in to the website builder',
                          content: 'testing 123'    
                       });

                    });
```

Maybe I have to bind click event on html components or play with the Library  jquery.orgchart.js?! If I put the same button in the page and not the orgchart, it works well.

[Image for modal that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCdwL.png)
If you need some others information to help me, just ask.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the solution for my popup hiding :

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                       $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                          placement: 'bottom',
                          trigger: 'hover',
                          title: 'Sign in to the website builder',
                          content: 'testing 123',
                          container: 'body' 
                       });

                    });
```

I add the tag container :'body' and my popup finally appear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution here : github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5889 I updated my post